# Pandas dynamic dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Point1":["Red","Red","Orange","Green","Yellow","Black"],"Point2":   ["Blue","Yellow","Green","Black","Black","Orange"]})
data["Red"] = [random.randint(-10,10) for p in range(0,6)]
data["Blue"] = [random.randint(-10,10) for p in range(0,6)]
data["Yellow"] = [random.randint(-10,10) for p in range(0,6)]
data["Green"] = [random.randint(-10,10) for p in range(0,6)]
data["Orange"] = [random.randint(-10,10) for p in range(0,6)]
data["Black"] = [random.randint(-10,10) for p in range(0,6)]
data["Number"] = [8,6,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]
```

Which looks like this:

```
    Point1  Point2  Red     Blue    Yellow  Green   Orange  Black Signal Number
0   Red     Blue    8        -5     0         1     0       2     Red    8
1   Red     Yellow  6        -7     5         6     5       3     Red    6
2   Orange  Green   -10      -9     5         8     10     -7     NaN    NaN
3   Green   Black   -3        4     1         5     -5      7     NaN    NaN
4   Yellow  Black   -2       -6     -6       -4     -10    -1     NaN    NaN
5   Black   Orange  10       -4     -9       -9     7      -3     NaN    NaN
```

What I need is to go through the DataFrame rows, row by row refreshing the "Signal" column (starting from the first NaN) based on current values of "Point1", "Point2" and past values of "Signal" itself and two previous values from "Number" (which itself is the corresponding color/value combination for signal, i.e. first value of Number is 8 because Red's first value is 8).

The rules for updating the signal column would be as follows:

Rule 1: Choose current period Point1 IF previous signal is same as that one. (i.e if col 2 row 3 (orange) is equal to col6 row 2 (red)) ELSE choose Point2.

Rule 2: If TWO previous values of Number are negative, choose Point2. If NOT choose Point1.

Rule 3: Same signal must be held for at least one period.

The DataFrame would then become:

```
    Point1  Point2  Red     Blue    Yellow  Green   Orange  Black Signal Number
0   Red     Blue    8        -5     0         1     0       2     Red    8
1   Red     Yellow  6        -7     5         6     5       3     Red    6
2   Orange  Green   -10      -9     5         8     10     -7     Orange 10
3   Green   Black   -3        4     1         5     -5      7     Orange -5
4   Yellow  Black   -2       -6     -6       -4     -10    -1     Black  -1
5   Black   Orange  10       -4     -9       -9     7      -3     Black  -3
```

I started by trying to switch the rows needed for the current period calculation but the problem is that I would have do the switch all over again for each row. Also, vectorized calculations seem impossible in this case.

Really stuck on this one, all help highly appreciated!

**Edit. I have maneged to come pretty close. Actually got it to work in IPython Notebook but for some reason does not work when I put it into a script:**

def func(data):

```
data["Signal_once"] = data["Signal"].shift(1)
data["Signal_twice"] = data["Signal"].shift(2)
data["Number_once"] = data["Number"].shift(1)
data["Number_twice"] = data["Number"].shift(2)

for i, signal in data.iterrows():

    if data.loc[i,"Signal"] == data.loc[i,"Point1"]:
        data.loc[i,"Signal"] = data.loc[i,"Point1"]
    elif data.loc[i,"Signal_once"] != data.loc[i,"Signal_twice"]:
        data.loc[i,"Signal"] = data.loc[i,"Signal_once"]
    elif (data.loc[i,"Number_once"] < 0) & (data.loc[i,"Number_twice"] < 0):
        data.loc[i,"Signal"] = data.loc[i,"Point2"]
    elif data.loc[i,"Point1"] != data.loc[i,"Signal_once"]:
        data.loc[i,"Signal"] = data.loc[i,"Point2"]
    else:
        data.loc[i,"Signal"] = data.loc[i,"Point1"]

    data["Signal_once"] = data["Signal"].shift(1)
    data["Signal_twice"] = data["Signal"].shift(2)
    data["Number_once"] = data["Number"].shift(1)
    data["Number_twice"] = data["Number"].shift(2)

data["Number"] = data.lookup(data.index, data["Signal"])

return data
```

For some reason it does not keep updating the switched rows for Number_once and Number_twice when I do it in Spyder. And as said, in IPython it works.

Comment: You might start by looking for conditional `apply` - there are plenty examples on how this can be done. Alternatively `numpy.where` can do `if... else` replacement/assignment. And for comparing current value(s) with previous ones `pandas` has `.shift` method, which you could use with any of the first two approaches.

Comment: Thx Primer. The problem is that when I First switch the rows I need to do it again for next row because the shited rows do not update.

Comment: I guess if you would illustrate the problem with the code you are using you could get more concrete help quicker on what needs to be done to fix it.

Comment: Okay cheers, I updated the original post to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Solved this by first filling the needed columns with dummy data and the putting the lookup in the loop.